# How to specify additional classpath in command line when running Spring Boot application via Maven?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, classpath, git-bash

I'm running an application (in GitBash on Windows) with:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Except that the application is looking for a properties file, which I'd like to make available in the classpath. But I don't want to have to change any code in this application.

Is there a way to specify additional classpaths when running this command? I've tried various forms of:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dclasspath="C:\\path\\to\\config\\dir"
```

or

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dclasspath=/C/path/to/config/dir
```

And I've tried setting `$CLASSPATH`.

None of this works, but I don't get a clear idea about where it is breaking because the only error is that my properties file cannot be found.

Comment: Try setting [`folders`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#folders) in Spring Boot Maven Plugin in the POM. But why do you want to do this to begin with?

Comment: That's just how this project is set up. It's a Tomcat web application and usually a config directory is added during deployment. I need to use a few different configurations, and don't want to be copying files around on my local machine if I can just change a command-line argument instead. When I run it from IntelliJ, I can add a runtime classpath in the IntelliJ project settings, which works fine.

Comment: Checkout the docs for spring boot here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html Note sections 69.3 also taking a loot at 24 which will tell you the order of how properties are loaded during runtime.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45710571/1838233

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding classpath to SpringBoot command line start when using maven-spring-boot-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710051/adding-classpath-to-springboot-command-line-start-when-using-maven-spring-boot-p)