# Adding classpath to SpringBoot command line start when using maven-spring-boot-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to add a classpath to when I run my spring boot application, which is run with the following command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I'm currently able to add a classpath folder to my maven tests, using custom arguments which inserted into the  field

However this approach has not worked for running the application with 
    mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: java has the standard `-cp` parameter, for maven, maybe you can put it into `MAVEN_OPTS`, but I didn't try it.

Comment: What do you mean by classpath folder? If you're using maven then dependencies should be declared in the pom. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I 'thought' I had a similar issue, where a dependency listed in my pom was ending up with a 'ClassNotFoundException' on startup. I wondered what I have to do. Turned out, I hadn't 'installed' it yet. After I installed it, my error disappeared. If you could provide more context, our answers could be clearer, and we'd know if it became resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) spawns a JVM which will, by default, include whatever your project says should be on the classpath e.g.

- `${project.build.outputDirectory}` this includes classes and resources
- dependencies declared in your project's POM

If you need to add things to this classpath, the plugin offers the following:

- [addResources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.run-goal.parameter-details.add-resources)
- [useTestClasspath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.run-goal.parameter-details.use-test-classpath)

For example, if you want to add this folder: `/this/that/theother` to the classpath then you would configure the spring-boot plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <folders>
            <folder>
                /this/that/theother
            </folder>
        </folders>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With that configuration in place, if you invoke `mvn spring-boot:run -X` you'll see that the additional folder is included on the front of the classpath ...

> [DEBUG] Classpath for forked process: /this/that/theother:...

Comment: OK, great question and answer. In my case I had to use: /this/that/theother/* for it to pick up the jars.

Comment: Seems that in spring-boot-maven-plugin 2.5.0 the `folders` configuration option was removed. But we can use `directories` instead - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-directories

Comment: Links not working anymore.

Comment: @geneb. thanks, I have updated the links

Answer (score 5):

if you dont want to modify your pom per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.run-goal.parameter-details.directories there are user properties too you can use from command line

in version 2.5.0 +

```
mvn -Dspring-boot.run.directories=/etc/bbcom spring-boot:run
```

prior you could use folders

```
mvn -Dspring-boot.run.folders=/etc/bbcom spring-boot:run
```

Comment: Link doesn't work.