# mvn spring-boot:run and Manually Add to Classpath

Tags: spring-boot, maven

There was a [previous thread on this which now has dead links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710051/adding-classpath-to-springboot-command-line-start-when-using-maven-spring-boot-p) and hasn't helped me.

I need to manually include a JAR file to the Classpath when running the Maven Spring Boot command

`mvn spring-boot:run`

The following didn't work, pointing to the folder of the JAR file:

```
mvn -Dspring-boot.run.folders=C:/Work/ spring-boot:run
```

When running the project in Elipse it's easy: I create a Run As  Configuration for the Application class where any additional JARs are added to the classpath under Dependencies:

[image]

I need to find the equivalent command-line solution for the Maven `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: Why manually? Why isn't it possible to simply add it as a dependency in maven?

Comment: We have this special case. For some reason our Maven Logback library suppresses logging and adding the JAR manually on top fixes the issue.

Comment: So instead of solving the issue you workaround it? It feels like some other logging library is in use instead of logback and adding it enables it again. What you can do, imho the easiest solution, is to create a maven profile which adds this dependency explicitly. You can then run locally with this profile, without resorting to other hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that in spring-boot-maven-plugin 2.5.0 the folders configuration option was removed. But we can use `directories` instead.
Try this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.directories=C:/Work/
```

If you got an error with window cmd, then try this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -D"spring-boot.run.directories"=C:/Work/
```